# How to invert colours on a layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I have a layer with a mask that was handed to me by a designer, and I wish to change the colours of it, but I'm having difficulty. Here it is, along with the thumbnail -

[image]

[image]

...If you look closely, you can see that something else was done to this layer, so there's actually a faded image in the background.

I'd like to retain this image, but basically make the black a light grey colour (same as the font), and the image elements (currently grey) darker/black, so pretty much an inversion of the current colours. Oh, and then the font would be black against the grey, but I can handle that part :)

Is this possible? If so, I'd be very very grateful to know how!

IMAGE WHEN OPACITY WAS RAISED TO 87%, OVERLAY - LUMINOSITY:

[image]

UPDATE:

This is how I can get it looking by inverting the image (although it's not the same image file you used - it's the original image with the layer mask applied, as displayed above), adding a levels adjustment to the group and dialing the middle slider all the way over to the LEFT, almost to the very end, at 4.20...

[image] 
[image]

...Not quite as good as yours, unfortunately! (i.e. Couldn't get the grey margin at the bottom to be the same grey as the crowd, just above it), so I'm guessing our methods are still different. Is it because you're using the png file rather than the layer with a mask?

Sorry, I think we're getting there...

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the mask layer:
   [image]
2. Go to Window -> (check) Properties
3. In the Properties window change your density
   [image]

---

If that doesn't solve, when you select your mask, tell what is your overlay mode in the fields on of your layer list:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. The first suggestion didn't do anything, but I raised the opacity (overlay - luminosity) and it began to look as I have attached up above... I am essentially trying to swap these tones/colours, so most of the whole layer is a light grey, with the bits that are currently grey being the darker ones. Or, if that will not work because it will make the center too dark, then something that will mean most of the layer is a light grey, with dark accents. Am I making sense? :) Thank you, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

**Going from the picture you provided** I hope its not too late.

[image]

Make a new levels adjustment.

[image]

Slide the middle slider left. Play around with the settings until you get a value you like. I find 2.79 works best.

[image]

Select color range and then sample the white text.

[image]

Play around with fuzziness until you only have the text selected. A value of 64 works best in this case.

[image]

Fill with black as many times as you need. I needed to fill twice.

**Method 2 - I think this is closer to what you are looking for.

[image]

Create a new levels adjustment layer

[image]

Slide middle slider to .40

[image]

### I apologize if I don't follow the usual conventions around here. This is one of my first posts/answers.

I'm not too sure what you are asking.

My initial thoughts was that you could just do control/command+i in photoshop but after rereading it, it doesn't seem to be the case.

However, I am still a bit confused on what exactly are you trying to do..

Where you looking for something like this?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is very close to what I am looking for :) I would just adjust the shade of grey myself. How did you do it? The only other thing is that the dark parts of the background image are still dark in this, and the light still light. Not essential, but if we could invert this it would be cool.

Comment: Okay! Sorry for taking so long to get back to ya! I'll edit the first post immediately!

Comment: Hi David, thank you! In fact, the image just below the phrase "Slide middle slider to 40" is EXACTLY what I'm looking for! Only problem is, I tried to follow your instructions but came a bit unstuck... One issue is that the layer in question still has a mask applied to it and exists amongst many other layers in the file, so the levels adjustment seems to apply to all. I tried doing it with a clipping mask but didn't quite get the desired results. According to your "Method 2," I should just be able to apply a levels adjustment to this layer and be done with it, right? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Well the base image that I started with is this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb3QM.png

I would suggest you group whatever layers you used to create this image, then create a levels adjustment layer ABOVE the group. That would give the desired effect.

Like this: http://i.imgur.com/hQU1HkV.png

Comment: Oh my goodness I am so sorry, I don't know how I missed it but you have to invert the image first (command/control + i) then create the level adjustment layer. A clipping mask will work.